# How to implement an interface explicitly with a virtual method?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface, virtual-functions

I can't do this

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    void MethodA();
}

class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    virtual void InterfaceA.MethodA()
    // Error: The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item
    {
    }
}
```

Where the following works

```
class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    public virtual void MethodA()
    {
    }
}
```

Why? How to circumvent this?

Comment: Why do you want to circumvent it? What benefit does that add?

Comment: @Eric It will save me some typing

Comment: How does not being allowed to mark an explicit interface method as being virtual cause you more typing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is because when a member is **explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface.**

So making something 'virtual' really does not make sense in this case, since virtual means that you intend to override it in an inherited class.  Implementing an interface *explicitly* **and** making it *virtual* would be contradictory. Which also may be why the compiler disallows this.

To work around it I think [csharptest.net's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337058/how-to-implement-an-interface-explicitly-with-a-virtual-method/3337232#3337232) or [Philip's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337058/how-to-implement-an-interface-explicitly-with-a-virtual-method/3337127#3337127) answer sounds like it would do the trick

Comment: Good explanation as to why it doesn't make sense to want that.

Answer (score 6):

It is part of the C# language specification:

> [It is a compile-time error for an explicit interface member implementation to include access modifiers, and it is a compile-time error to include the modifiers abstract, virtual, override, or static.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

According to C# language spec:

> It is a compile-time error for an
>   explicit interface member
>   implementation to include access
>   modifiers, and it is a compile-time
>   error to include the modifiers
>   abstract, virtual, override, or
>   static.

You can "get around" it only by calling your virtual method from the explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something like this:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    void MethodA();
}

class ClassA : InterfaceA
{
    void InterfaceA.MethodA()
    { MethodB(); }

    protected virtual void MethodB()
    { 
    }
}
```

Often this is a superior approach anyway as the internal method may change signature without changing the interface.  Take a more real-word example:

```
interface IOrderDetails
{
    void PlaceOrder();
}

//Sometime later you extend with:
interface IOrderDetails2 : IOrderDetails
{
    void PlaceOrder(IUser user);
}

//Implementation
class Order : IOrderDetails, IOrderDetails2
{
    static readonly IUser AnonUser;

    void IOrderDetails.PlaceOrder()
    { OnPlaceOrder(AnonUser); }
    void IOrderDetails2.PlaceOrder(IUser user)
    { OnPlaceOrder(user); }

    protected virtual void OnPlaceOrder(IUser user)
    { 
    }
}
```

Here you can see as the IOrderDetails2 was added we can safely refactor the existing virtual method (thus generating compile-time errors for derivations).  Additionally this often allows you to provide common functionality, logging, and exception handling in the base implementation class...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the virtual modifier with the static, abstract, **private** or override modifiers.
default modifier is private

Comment: Interestingly for explicit implementations the modifier is public, though it can only be accessed if the instance is cast to the respective interface type.